# algorithm for calculating texture tile coordinates in 3d model generated based on height map

Tags: algorithm, textures, procedure, heightmap

I'm converting height map into 3d model, I have a small texture that meant to represent 4 points (i.e. 2 triangles). The problem is a texture tiling when a height difference between points is too large. I'd like to tile my texture in order to avoid high stretching, but I have problem implement general-case algorithm. I have rendered pictures, to represent what I mean:

[image: collage with pictures i rendered]

in this examples I use only half of texture (1 triangle), all texture coordinates I set manually.

please help me find algorithm for calculation texture coordinates in general case

code:

```
class procedure GraphicEngine.AddHeightmapQuad(X, Y, Z1, Z2, Z3, Z4: Double);
const
  Length = 1;
var
  Vertices: PVertex;
  v1, v2, v3, v4: TD3DVector;
begin
  OleCheck(Triangles.Lock(TrianglesCount * 3 * SizeOf(TVertex), 2 * 3 * SizeOf(TVertex), Pointer(Vertices), 0));
  Dec(Vertices);

  Vertices[1]:= TVertex.Create(X         , Y         , Z1,  0,  0);
  Vertices[2]:= TVertex.Create(X + Length, Y         , Z2,  1,  0);
  Vertices[3]:= TVertex.Create(X         , Y + Length, Z3,  0,  1);

  Vertices[4]:= TVertex.Create(X + Length, Y         , Z2,  1,  0);
  Vertices[5]:= TVertex.Create(X         , Y + Length, Z3,  0,  1);
  Vertices[6]:= TVertex.Create(X + Length, Y + Length, Z4,  1,  1);

  D3DXVec3Subtract(v1, Vertices[2].vec, Vertices[1].vec);
  D3DXVec3Subtract(v2, Vertices[3].vec, Vertices[1].vec);

  D3DXVec3Subtract(v3, Vertices[4].vec, Vertices[6].vec);
  D3DXVec3Subtract(v4, Vertices[5].vec, Vertices[6].vec);

  Vertices[2].U:= Sqrt(1 + Sqr(v1.z));
  Vertices[3].V:= Sqrt(1 + Sqr(v2.z));

  Vertices[4].U:= Sqrt(1 + Sqr(v4.z));
  Vertices[5].V:= Sqrt(1 + Sqr(v3.z));

  Vertices[6].U:= Sqrt(1 + Sqr(v4.z));
  Vertices[6].V:= Sqrt(1 + Sqr(v3.z));     

  Inc(TrianglesCount, 2);

  OleCheck(Triangles.Unlock);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the exact stretch on the texture by calculating the actual size of the triangle. Even easier you can simply compute the length of the edges to adjust the coordinates. Fix one point to be 0,0 in the texture then the next one instead of `0, 1` would be `0, sqrt(1 + (h1 - h2)^2)` and the same for the other point of the grid (h1 and h2 are the heights of the points). To avoid mismatches make sure you copy the coordinates when you do the next cell.

Comment: output is correct in first two cases, but incorrect in third case:
[link](http://tau.rghost.ru/6QxYDDWrX/image.png)

Comment: Can you try it on a larger grid? This setup will ensure that you still match the tiles on the neighboring cells. If you don't care about that you can change one of the points to be `dot(norm(v1), norm(v2)) * sqrt(1 + (h1 - h2)^2), sqrt(1 + (h1 - h2)^2))` where v1 and v2 are the vectors from the 0,0 point to the other vertices of the triangle.

Comment: I make 7x7 grid.
since my texture should be tiled only on heightmap quad, I think, only first triangle should match second triangle in quad, but I think i misuse something, because this two triangles doesn't look tiled well: [link](http://tau.rghost.ru/6JXrZK2ZC/image.png). 
I add code to my first post, maybe you can point out an error

Comment: You can't have both no jump and no warping. Not with a normal 2d texture. You have to pick one or the other.